# i3 WM mouse left click problem

Tags: i3-wm

I've used i3 on Ubuntu 18.04 for the last few months.
In the last month after using the computer for few hours, the left click of my mouse stops working (the right one still works).

In most of the time, it happens after lock + unlock of the computer (sill not sure what's the trigger).

Any idea what causes the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The temporary fix which I execute is jump into a TTY session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then logging back in.